# Magick++.h not found when trying from Cmake

Tags: cmake, imagemagick

Hello I am trying to use ImageMagick++ in one of my applications. I am trying to build my program from CMakeList. When I try to include Magick++.h in my main program it is showing an error saying that it cannot be found.

I tried to install like it is mentioned in the link. 
[Link for installation.](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Install.html)

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(...)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
#set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig")
#set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "/usr/local/lib")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

find_package(libhpdf REQUIRED)
find_package(ImageMagick REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")

include_directories(${LIBHPDF_INCLUDE_DIRS} src/include)
include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})


message(Verification "${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES} ${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS}")


set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp src/base64.cpp src/base64.h)
add_executable(pdfgen ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(pdfgen ${LIBHPDF_LIBRARIES} ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES})
```

Can someone help me to resolve this issue

This is the CMake output
[Cmake output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56zo9.png)

Message for ImageMagickLibraries is null

Comment: What OS? What version of ImageMagick do you have? How and where did you install it?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, Imagemagick 7.0.6.10 and /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig has the .pc files and usr/local/include/imagemagick-7 has the magick++.h header file

Comment: Did you try `find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++)`

Comment: Just did. Still the message us blank like shown in the image.

Comment: Double check that all `CMakeCache.txt` have been removed. The `find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++ REQUIRED)` should be all that's needed.

Comment: Yeah I have removed the cache. CMake build is failing when I use find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++ REQUIRED) instead of find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++)

Comment: According to `message(Verification)` output, ImageMagick variable you use for include directories is empty (or does'n not exist). Does your project contain `FindImageMagick.cmake` script, which is used instead of one shipped with CMake?

Comment: You didn't answer *how* you installed **ImageMagick**. Did you maybe configure `--without-magick-plus-plus`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev My project doesn't contain FindImageMagick.cmake. Since I could specify the path to .pc files I thought it is not required. I don't know why it is showing the message. Should I include one.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have provided a link for installation and my OS is Ubuntu 16.

Comment: ./configure, make, sudo make install to install it. I can see Magic++.h in include.

Comment: Call `find_package(ImageMagick)` executes `FindImageMagick.cmake` script. Whether this script uses pkg-config or not, it is dependent on the script itself. As for path to `.pc` files, you *may* specify it, but your current code doesn't do that. In any case, this is unrelated here, because call to `find_package()` succeed (otherwise with *REQUIRED* keyword CMake would generate an error message). But emptiness of `ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIR` and `ImageMagick_LIBRARIES` variables looks strange: CMake-shipped script should set them.